# Heading the right way on c matrix code?

Tags: c, matrix

My instructor said the way to start this is to use the getline() function from out book, then get the numbers from the line, then have those numbers in matrix form,  I do not understand why I would use getline?

//eventually this code should take in a square matrix and from 2x2 to 6x6
//the plan is to get it to read in a line, then get the numbers from the line, 
//then print out the numbers in a matrix form.  That is the goal for today.
//later I will try to get the actual matrix part working

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

//error list for error checking will need later I guess (from my notes)
#define ENDOFFILE -1 
#define TOOMANYNUMS -2
#define LIMIT  256

//functions declared
int get_line(char line[], int);

//main
main(){
char line[255];
int num[6];
printf("Please input numbers %c: ", line);
get_line(line,LIMIT);


}

//functions 
  int get_line(char s[],int lim){
  int c, i;
    for (i=0;i<lim-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n'; ++i)
  s[i] = c;
if(c=='\n'){
s[i]=c;
  ++i; 
}
s[i]='\0';
return i;
}
```

Comment: "The plan is to read in a line..."  "I do not understand why I would use getline".     Where is the disconnect?

Comment: getline just returns the length of the line, why is that needed?

Comment: your get_line() implementation is horrible, have a look at ANSI C function "fgets"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The getline(char[], int) function reads characters from the console with getchar() and stores them in the array s[].  The array s[] points at the same memory as the line[] array in the main() function.

Comment: @RD for testing purposed how do I print out the line I typed in? I called getline(), then: printf("%d",line); and I get the same output out no matter what is typed:  2673685.

Comment: The variable line is a pointer to an array of memory locations containing chars.  When you use %d with printf() you are asking for the integer value stored at line, which is 2673685.  That is the memory address of the first location in your array.  Try using %s or the function puts() instead.

Answer (score 1):

`getline` is not just returning the lenth of the line, it's also copying the first line into the `s` parameter.  So after your call of `getline(line,LIMIT)` (which doesn't btw, store the return value anywhere), the `line` variable will contain the first line.

*Edit: I should also point out that your `printf` just above the call to getline is referencing the `line` variable, which is uninitialized and a char array, not a single character*

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, so I do not know how to fix this.  I thought I knew what you meant and tried to fix it, but only got more errors.